# Sending data between two php functions using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am currently working on user verification on the website. What I am trying to do is to ask the user to input the credentials and push the "send confirmation" button, then send the code to the user using something (SMS or messenger) and make the user insert this code into the field and click "confirm" to check if it is correct. The Issue that I am facing right now is how do I pass the correct code from one PHP function (which I currently call using ajax) to the other. For obvious reasons of security I can't just send the code through JavaScript, but you are welcome to prove me wrong :) . Here is the HTML that I have:

```
<button type="button" onclick="send_sms()">Send verification</button><br>
    Code from the SMS: <input type="text" id="fi" value=""><br>
    <p id="res"></p>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="check_sms()">Check</button>
    
    <script>    
    function check_sms() {

      jQuery.post(
            ajax_object.ajax_url,
            {action: "confirm_sms",
             code: document.getElementById("fi").value
            },
            function( response ) {
                // showing the result of confirmation
                document.getElementById("res").textContent = response;
            }
      );
    }
    
    function send_sms() {
        jQuery.post(
            ajax_object.ajax_url,
            {action: "send_sms",
             phone: document.getElementById("phone").value
            },
            function( response ) {
                // temporarely showing the code in console (shold not be there )
                console.log("not an sms, but the code for now is " + response);
            }
        );
    }
    </script>
```

Now, in functions.php I have:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_confirm_sms', 'confirm_sms' );

function confirm_sms() {
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    
    // yes, I know that it will not output anything after, but it is beside the point anyway.
    // and yes, I will not send the real code as the output of the function (just for testing)
    wp_send_json($_SESSION['real_sms_code']);
    if ($code != $_SESSION['real_sms_code']) {
        wp_send_json('The code is not correct, please, try again');
        return;
    }
    wp_send_json("Nice code, awesome balls!");
}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_sms', 'send_sms' );
function send_sms() {
    // my attempt at storing the code, not the same session as I suspected, but was worth a try
    $_SESSION['real_sms_code'] = strval(rand(100000, 999999));
    wp_send_json($_SESSION['real_sms_code']);
}
```

The issue here is that the `confirm_sms` function always outputs `'None'` (It should be the code set by the other function) and I can't figure out how to fix that. I was thinking about just creating a file containing this code, but

a) It is unreliable

b) I can't (reliably) identify which user the code belongs to since this is before they are registered

c) This may be slow with many users

There is got to be a better way of handling this.

Comment: It's always `None` because you're essentially resetting the session value any time you call your PHP script: `$_SESSION['real_sms_code'] = 'None';`

Comment: You should remove this line, `$_SESSION['real_sms_code'] = 'None';` or keep it in `send_sms()`, currently it doesn't make sense to say it is none, while you are forcefully making it "none".

Comment: @MohammedKhurram  @nitrin0, yes, that was quite dumb of me, but I have tried removing this line, though in that case, JavaScript never receives a response for some reason. This may happen due to an error in the code somewhere, and I'm guessing that it is the absence of ```real_sms_code``` attribute.

Comment: I have fixed the above mentioned issue in the question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured out the issue: I have copied the `$_SESSION` part from somewhere, but the guy there never mentioned that you have to use `session_start();` before the functions in PHP. Now it works flawlessly. Kinda frustrating that I have lost a day because of someone not posting the whole code, please don't be like that :)